# CKeditor with Rails 4 mime type error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ckeditor

CKEditor was working fine for me in development. But on my production server it gives me the following error:

```
Refused to execute script from '/assets/ckeditor/lang/en.js?t=FB9E' because its MIME type ('text/html') is not executable, and strict MIME type checking is enabled.
```

I don't know what is the problem!

Comment: So what I checked was the lang folder was not precompiling. I copied it from development server and pasted it in production server. Now it works.

Comment: Any idea why it wasn't precompiling? I'm facing a similar issue where the language files are not being precompiled in production even though I've included it in assets.rb in Rails 5.

Comment: Oh, my bad, I didn't read your error message entirely. I had trouble with having the lang folder being precompiled so I had to do this to get it working -> `Rails.application.config.assets.precompile += %w(ckeditor/* ckeditor/lang/*)`.